# Xcode 4.3 -> SVN issue "Project has no default build configuration"

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn, xcode4.3

When I check out the code on Xcode 4.3, it gives an error - Project has no default build configuration. It works on previous Xcode versions though.

Can anyone help me in figuring this out?

https://devforums.apple.com/message/629197#629197

I am unable to use Xcode 4.3 now and I have updated my iPhone to 5.1

In order to test app on my phone I need to fix this Xcode issue. Can someone help me in figuring this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Xcode 4.3 requires that your "defaultConfigurationName" must be something defined in the "XCBuildConfiguration" section.

1. Open your project.pbxproj in a text editor like emacs / textmate.
2. Search for "XCBuildConfiguration" and note the build configurations defined in that section (usually Debug, Release and Distribution, depending on the configurations you defined for your project).
3. Now search all instances of "defaultConfigurationName" - it's likely that this is set to a configuration that does NOT exist in your XCBuildConfiguration section. Change the value(s) so that it matches one of the configurations specified in XCBuildConfiguration (in my case, I just changed from "Release" to "Debug", which should probably work in your case as well because most projects have at least a "Debug" configuration defined)

You should then be able to open your project in XCode 4.3